# image upload but getting Error : Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I try to upload image in codeigniter but i have got
Error : Unknown column 'Array' in 'field

```
public function do_imageupload(){

    $config['upload_path'] = './imguploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = '5120';
    $config['max_width']  = '1500';
    $config['max_height']  = '1500';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    if ( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']) ) die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')) 
                {

                    $arrayName = array( 
                                        'image'=>$this->upload->data()
                                       );

                    $this->Image_model->insert_image($arrayName);// error here 

                } 
                else 
                {
                     echo 'errorrrr';
                }


    }
```

Error Message: Array to string conversion

how can solve this tell me any suggestion

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `img_upload` (`image`) VALUES (Array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are getting image data in the array.

```
$arrayName = array( 
                   'image'=>$this->upload->data()
                   );

$this->upload->data() // returns an array.
```

To get the file name you have to pass a parameter called `file_name` like `$this->upload->data('file_name')`.